Delete rows based on condition from SQL Server using Databricks Notebook
In a Databricks notebook I'm calling my custom function that creates a session for connecting to a SQL Server database:
spark = jdbc_spark_session(
    database=database,
    username=username,
    password=password
)

And I have the below function that I'd like to delete rows from SQL Server using this query: DELETE FROM A WHERE EventId < 1000;
when I try the below, it just 'overwrites' or deletes ALL rows and completely ignores my query based on eventid..
def delete_old_records():
    delete_query = """
    DELETE FROM A
    WHERE EventId < 1000
    """
    
    # Establish JDBC connection
    connection = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="A", properties=connectionProperties).write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="A", mode='overwrite', properties=connectionProperties)
    
    # Execute delete query
    connection.cursor().execute(delete_query)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

# Call the function to delete old records
delete_old_records()

I've also tried using .write and it does the same thing:
    view_df = spark.sql(delete_query )
view_df.write.jdbc(url=spark._jdbc_url, table=sql_table, mode='overwrite', properties=spark._connection_properties)


Don't use Spark for that.  Use JDBC or ODBC directly.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft you're right!

I agree with @David Browne - Microsoft you can use it with JDBC or ODBC.
+-------+---------+
|EventId|EventName|
+-------+---------+
|  10001|  Event A|
|  10002|  Event B|
|  10003|  Event C|
+-------+---------+

I have tried the below approach in the %scala :
%scala
import java.util.Properties
import java.sql.DriverManager
val jdbcUsername = "admin02"
val jdbcPassword = "Welcome@1"
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://dilipsqlser.database.windows.net:1433;database=db02;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", jdbcUsername)
connectionProperties.put("password", jdbcPassword)
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val sql = "DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventId < 10003"
val stmt = connection.createStatement()
stmt.execute(sql)
stmt.close()
connection.close()
println("Rows with EventId < 1003 have been deleted.")


In the above code I setup the JDBC connection properties
Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password
parameters.
Establishing JDBC connection & Creating a SQL DELETE query
Executing the DELETE query

Results:
Rows with EventId < 1003 have been deleted.


